# Online radio streaming app for Android: where to place Wakelock and Wifilock

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-wake-lock

I'm creating an online radio stream app and i have a problem with the wakelock and wifilock.

Where to place the wakelock/wifilock so that the app doesn't stop playing and not going to sleep?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class myMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

    private Button buttonPlay;

    private Button buttonStopPlay;

    private MediaPlayer player;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initializeUIElements();

        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void initializeUIElements() {

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        }

        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="package.your.RadioStream"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".myMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These attributes go  in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  You may need the following for your app to work correctly:

```
<android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" uses-permission />    
<android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" uses-permission />
<android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" uses-permission /> 
<android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" uses-permission />
<android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" uses-permission />
```

Code in java file for wifi lock.

```
// obtain wifi lock
wifiLock = ((WifiManager) 

THIS_CONTEXT.getSystemService(THIS_CONTEXT.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock("clientWifiLock");
wifiLock.acquire();
```

Do similarly for wake lock.

Comment: and what do i need to add in the java file. Where to add wakelock.acquire() and wakelock.release()?